# How to bulk move files to similarly named folders?

Tags: vba, powershell

I am attempting to bulk move my files to new folders that have new names.  For example, I want to move all files from:

C:\cat\
C:\dog\

To:

C:\test\cat-1234\
C:\test\dog-2477\

I have about 400 folders that I want to move this way.

The destination folder will always CONTAIN the original folder name.

Comment: Any reasons why you want to use VBA to move files? It is probably not the most appropriate language to do that.

Comment: @assylias What would be an appropriate language to do this?  The only reason I wanted to use VBA was so that I could debug the code if there were issues.  I imagine a PowerShell script would probably be best, but I'm not very familiar with PS.

Comment: I am not familiar with PS either, but I would have thought indeed that this is something that a shell script would do well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can copy files from one folder to the other. You can use the API `SHFileOperation` :) It will also give you the animated look which you see when windows copies files from 1 folder to the other :) Here is an example. Please amend it for your actual needs.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function SHFileOperation _
Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHFileOperationA" _
(lpFileOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT) As Long

Private Type SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    hWnd As Long
    wFunc As Long
    pFrom As String
    pTo As String
    fFlags As Integer
    fAborted As Boolean
    hNameMaps As Long
    sProgress As String
End Type

Private Const FO_COPY = &H2

Sub Sample()
    Dim FilePath1 As String, FilePath2 As String

    FilePath1 = "C:\cat"
    FilePath2 = "C:\test\cat-1234"

    '~~> Usage ~~> CopyFolder(From,To)
    '~~> Example ~~> CopyFolder("C:\Temp\1","C:\Temp\2")
    If CopyFolder(FilePath1, FilePath2) Then
        MsgBox "Copied"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not copied"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function CopyFolder(ByVal sFrom As String, _
ByVal sTo As String) As Boolean
    Dim SHFileOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    CopyFolder = False
    With SHFileOp
        .wFunc = FO_COPY
        .pFrom = sFrom
        .pTo = sTo
    End With
    SHFileOperation SHFileOp
    CopyFolder = True
    Exit Function
Whoa:
    MsgBox "Following error occurd while copying folder " & sFrom & vbCrLf & _
    Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error message"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such thing as bulk move, even if you write a batch program, the OS will only let you do it one file at the time.